# Как увеличить пинг?

Tags: javascript, сокет, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Делаю игру на сокетах, чтобы сделать отладку интерполяции и экстраполяции нужно увеличить пинг и возможно эмулировать потерю пакетов на открытой вкладке в Chrome. Может быть у кого то была подобная задача, нашёл только через виртуалку WANem http://habrahabr.ru/post/127274/

Но не очень хочется поднимать целую виртуалку для небольшой задачи.

Comment: Если у вас линух, то практически всё есть под рукой сразу же. Надо только этим уметь пользоваться, поэтому проще всякие WANem. В общем случае нужен какой-то так называемый шейпер(shaper). Напустить его на интересующий трафик, путь притормаживает, лишние пакеты отбрасывает (если умеет).

Comment: [в настройках хрома есть настройки сети](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#network-conditions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В developer tools есть уже все что нужно.

1. Нажать f12.
2. В верхнем левом углу нажать на иконку телефона.
3. Вверху будет секция network и там в старых версиях будет список возможных задержек, а в новых - кнопка "configure throttling". Там можно как увеличить пинг, так и ограничить скорость соединения.